# I need to work on multitasking in Iphone SDK 4.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Actually I am looking for Multitasking in Iphone SDK 4.0 and want to run to apps at the same time as it does in Ipod application for Iphone like songs while u can use different apps also. Is there any idea that how to use that feature in Iphone SDK 4.0 beta.

I have tried multiple NSThread but runs on same view or differnt but cant figured out to run 2 apps at same time.

Comment: I think iOS 4.0 is still under NDA so we can't discuss it here.  There is documentation at http://developer.apple.com/technologies/iphone/whats-new.html if you are a member of the developer program.

Comment: Why can't we discuss it here? You can develop with it.

Comment: @thyrgle because anyone who has access to iOS 4 has agreed to an NDA about it.  This means the only legit place they can ask questions about it before the NDA is lifted is on http://devforums.apple.com

Comment: Oh.. Legal issues. I see then.

Answer (score 0):

I think the spirit of the NDA needs to be honored, and details, as well as specific API calls or even links to specific docs for 4.0 should not be posted.

At the same time, in my mind, there's some leeway to talk about fundamentals like this question that have been asked in variants again and again here, since there's clearly no harm in setting fellow developers on the right track.

That said, here's my answer: 4.0's interpretation of Multitasking can't run arbitrary third party apps as full blown background processes. You can't keep any code running in the background. They have to conform to certain types of approved services that Apple has chosen for 4.0, based on common app and developer demands.

If you're asking specifically about an app that plays music in the background (similar to a new Pandora app will under 4.0), you want to support the 'audio' background mode, as discussed in the document titled 'Supporting Multitasking In Your Applications' and linked from the 4.0 SDK section of the Apple developer site. This has been discussed in public keynotes, which is why I think it's fair game to give as an answer here.

If you have further questions, and are a paying Apple developer, you can discuss the 4.0 SDK on their [developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com).